# Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function L.TileLayer.BetterWMS function

Tags: django, leaflet, geoserver

I'm trying to display an onclick popup for my wms but I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function.

I followed the instructions and downloaded jquery-3.3.1.js from this site: http://jquery.com/%20download/#jquery and pasted it in my static folder together with L.TileLayer.BetterWMS.js which is located at the same directory but I still cannot see the attributes of the line layer. This is my code:

index.html

```
{% extends 'workorders/base.html' %}
{% block jumbotron2 %}
<div class="jumbotron">
<h1>Navbar example</h1>
<p class="lead">This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the top-aligned navbar works. As you scroll, this navbar remains in its original position and moves with the rest of the page.</p>
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="../../components/navbar/" role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
{% load static %}
{% load leaflet_tags %}
<head>
  {% leaflet_js %}
  {% leaflet_css %}
  <title>Map</title>
  <style type="text/css">
      #gis {width: 100%;height:600px;}
  </style>
     <style type="text/css">
       #map {
        width: 100%;height:600px;
      }
    </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'dist/leaflet-groupedlayercontrol/leaflet.groupedlayercontrol.min.css' %}">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'dist/leaflet.ajax.js' %}" > </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'dist/leaflet-groupedlayercontrol/leaflet.groupedlayercontrol.min.js' %}" > </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'L.TileLayer.BetterWMS.js' %}" > </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'jquery-3.3.1.min.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


      var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [42,21],
        zoom: 7
      });


      L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

        var datasets = L.tileLayer.wms('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/geodjango/wms', {
        layers: 'geodjango:layer_ww_manholes',
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true
        });

      var lines = L.tileLayer.betterWms('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/geodjango/wms', {
        layers: 'geodjango:layer_ww_lines',
        transparent: true,
        format: 'image/png'
      });

        datasets.addTo(map);
        lines.addTo(map);


       var basemaps = {
          OSM: L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
          })
      };

        var groupedOverlays = {
          "Layers": {
            "ww_manholes": datasets,
            "ww_lines": lines
          }

        };

        L.control.groupedLayers(basemaps, groupedOverlays).addTo(map);   

</script>

</body>
</html>
{% endblock %}

      L.TileLayer.BetterWMS.js

L.TileLayer.BetterWMS = L.TileLayer.WMS.extend({

  onAdd: function (map) {
    // Triggered when the layer is added to a map.
    //   Register a click listener, then do all the upstream WMS things
    L.TileLayer.WMS.prototype.onAdd.call(this, map);
    map.on('click', this.getFeatureInfo, this);
  },

  onRemove: function (map) {
    // Triggered when the layer is removed from a map.
    //   Unregister a click listener, then do all the upstream WMS things
    L.TileLayer.WMS.prototype.onRemove.call(this, map);
    map.off('click', this.getFeatureInfo, this);
  },

  getFeatureInfo: function (evt) {
    // Make an AJAX request to the server and hope for the best
    var url = this.getFeatureInfoUrl(evt.latlng),
        showResults = L.Util.bind(this.showGetFeatureInfo, this);
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      success: function (data, status, xhr) {
        var err = typeof data === 'string' ? null : data;
        showResults(err, evt.latlng, data);
      },
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        showResults(error);  
      }
    });
  },

  getFeatureInfoUrl: function (latlng) {
    // Construct a GetFeatureInfo request URL given a point
    var point = this._map.latLngToContainerPoint(latlng, this._map.getZoom()),
        size = this._map.getSize(),

        params = {
          request: 'GetFeatureInfo',
          service: 'WMS',
          srs: 'EPSG:4326',
          styles: this.wmsParams.styles,
          transparent: this.wmsParams.transparent,
          version: this.wmsParams.version,      
          format: this.wmsParams.format,
          bbox: this._map.getBounds().toBBoxString(),
          height: size.y,
          width: size.x,
          layers: this.wmsParams.layers,
          query_layers: this.wmsParams.layers,
          info_format: 'text/html'
        };

    params[params.version === '1.3.0' ? 'i' : 'x'] = point.x;
    params[params.version === '1.3.0' ? 'j' : 'y'] = point.y;

    return this._url + L.Util.getParamString(params, this._url, true);
  },

  showGetFeatureInfo: function (err, latlng, content) {
    if (err) { console.log(err); return; } // do nothing if there's an error

    // Otherwise show the content in a popup, or something.
    L.popup({ maxWidth: 800})
      .setLatLng(latlng)
      .setContent(content)
      .openOn(this._map);
  }
});

L.tileLayer.betterWms = function (url, options) {
  return new L.TileLayer.BetterWMS(url, options);  
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You've to import from `js/` folder at the top of all `<script>` imports...

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/L.TileLayer.BetterWMS.js' %}"></script>
  ```

Comment: Are you sure that all Javascript imports are working ? Open the Network set Developer in Chrome/Firefox... *`F12`* + *`Network`* + *`Ctrl+F5`*

Comment: L.TileLayer.BetterWMS.js:21 Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
    at e.getFeatureInfo (L.TileLayer.BetterWMS.js:21)
    at e.fire (leaflet.js:5)
    at e._fireDOMEvent (leaflet.js:5)
    at e._handleDOMEvent (leaflet.js:5)
    at HTMLDivElement.r (leaflet.js:5)

Comment: Ok, try this: 

`var wmsLayer = L.tileLayer.wms('https://demo.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/ows?', {
    layers: 'ne:ne'
}).addTo(map);`
[WMS in Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/examples/wms/wms.html#wms-in-leaflet)

Comment: jquery-3.3.1 i think is not being imported

Comment: I have it under the static folder just copied the script and pasted it. Don't know why it is not working?

Comment: Add to your question the hierarchy of your folders tree. :)

Comment: I edited the question and included a picture I think it seen clearly in the pic

Comment: Ok men, I was right the Jquery ref link it's the next: `<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js' %}"></script>
`
I'm going to edit my answer :)

Comment: it seems now that jquery is being imported but I still get no popups. Should I modify the jquery file maybe ?

Comment: Ok, you are missing the other javascript file. Take a look to the modify answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178351/discussion-between-r-garcia-and-gent-bytyqi).

Comment: how can I reach you my chat is not activated

Comment: @GentBytyqi ?? Just, enter to the [previous link](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178351/discussion-between-r-garcia-and-gent-bytyqi)

Comment: Man I solved it. JQuery was being imported in another template as well and thats why it didn't work. Thanks for the help !

Comment: Ohh perfect i'm glad! Remember set vote Up to my answer ;)
And if you'll need any help with Django, contact me